# Why do transitions between two `GoRoute`s with `pageBuilder` transitions not work in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, transition, flutter-go-router

#### Summary

I want to set up entry and exit transitions in flutter. I'm using the [`go_router`](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router) package and navigate via `context.go`. I have set up a working transition on `GoRoute`. However, setting up a transition on another `GoRoute` and navigating between the two causes the transition to break. I need help understanding why.

---

#### Full

I have two views, `ViewA` and `ViewB` like this:

```dart
class ViewA extends StatelessWidget {
  const ViewA({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5), () {
      context.go("/B");
    });
    return /* ... */;
  }
}

class ViewB extends StatelessWidget {
  const ViewB({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5), () {
      context.go("/A");
    });
    return /* ... */;
  }
}
```

I have set up routes for these views like this:

```dart
final routes = GoRouter(routes: <RouteBase>[
  GoRoute(
    path: "/A",
    pageBuilder: (context, state) => CustomTransitionPage(
      child: const ViewA(),
      transitionDuration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
      transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) =>
          FadeTransition(
              opacity:
                  CurveTween(curve: Curves.easeInOutCirc).animate(animation),
              child: child),
    ),
  ),
  GoRoute(
    path: "/B",
    pageBuilder: (context, state) => CustomTransitionPage(
        child: const ViewB(),
        transitionDuration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
        transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) =>
            FadeTransition(
              opacity:
                  CurveTween(curve: Curves.easeInOutCirc).animate(animation),
              child: child,
            ),
    ),
  ),
]);
```

However, this results in no transition at all. If I instead change the second route to

```dart
GoRoute(
  path: "/B",
  builder: (context, state) => const ViewB(),
),
```

The animation from `"B" -> "A"` uses a fade transition as expected whereas `"A" -> "B"` falls back on the default transition animation.

- How can I get a fade transition both ways between `A` and `B`?
- Why do the transitions stop working if I define one for each route?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this has to do with the ValueKey.

If you check out the examples provided in the official repo, you will find this: https://github.com/flutter/packages/blob/main/packages/go_router/example/lib/transition_animations.dart

```
CustomTransitionPage<void>(
          key: state.pageKey,
          child: const DetailsScreen(),
          transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 150),
          transitionsBuilder: (BuildContext context,
              Animation<double> animation,
              Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
              Widget child) {
            // Change the opacity of the screen using a Curve based on the the animation's
            // value
            return FadeTransition(
              opacity:
                  CurveTween(curve: Curves.easeInOut).animate(animation),
              child: child,
            );
          }
```

Passing in the key `state.pageKey` seems to fix it for me

My transition:

```
CustomTransitionPage appContentTransition(
    {required Widget child, required ValueKey<String> pageKey}) {
  return CustomTransitionPage(
      key: pageKey,
      child: child,
      transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
        return SlideTransition(
            position: Tween<Offset>(
              begin: Offset(1.0,
                  0.0),
              end: Offset.zero,
            ).animate(animation),
            child: child);
      });
}
```